# What regex to filter this

Tags: regex

Need help in making regular expression to filter some URI.
I got this URI

```
/bii-rib/js/jquery.tools.min.js
/images/navRightEdge.gif
/corp/combined.js.h-966868872.pack
/images/popup_in.jpg
/corp/reporting/html
/biivapg/
/images/icon.ico
/common/ibChannel.do
/common/Login.do
/common/login.do
/ib101/ibLoginSecurityQuestion.do
/ib104/ibThirdPartyTransferDetails.do
/abc-admin/ss102/userEnquiryScreen.do
/COMMON/LOGIN.DO
/corp/pending.do
/corp/front/withholdingtax.do
/corp/admin/group.do
```

I need to filter that URL in order to get only this URI

```
/common/ibChannel.do
/common/Login.do
/common/login.do
/ib101/ibLoginSecurityQuestion.do
/ib104/ibThirdPartyTransferDetails.do
/abc-admin/ss102/userEnquiryScreen.do
/COMMON/LOGIN.DO
```

What regex in order to get the result above?

Thanks all.

Comment: You have simply given input and output, but you didn't gave what is the criteria for the filtering

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a regex like this:

```
/^\/corp\/.*|(.*.do)/igm
```

And use substitution `$1`.

[[Regex Demo]](https://regex101.com/r/iX9cC1/2)

or this:

```
/^(?!\/corp)(.*\.do)$/igm
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this RegEx: `^(?=\/[aCci].{4,8}\/.+\.(do|DO)$).*`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/zT0hA8/2).